# Triggering List public methods to resize row heights

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, refs

Even after successfully setting a List ref (as shown in the tree.js example), I seem to be unable to successfully trigger a remeasuring of row heights using [public methods](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#public-methods) (also shown in the tree.js example).

https://plnkr.co/edit/V2JhJL8ZGknrbYgRWDhf?p=preview

```
var listRef;
function setRef (ref) {
  listRef = ref
  return ref;
}

<List
    ref={setRef}
    ...
/>


listRef.forceUpdateGrid()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the listRef.recomputeCellSizesAndPositions() method, it should do what you want.